# Visual Studio VSTO-Add-In. How can I have a Document Unique ID (database ID) in my MS Word Document when it's downloaded from the Web Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, vsto

Our Vertical SaaS ERP enables users to manage documents. Through the Web Application (documents are directly uploaded from the web interface), also we've MS Word VSTO Add-In which allows saving documents to cloud from MS Word directly to the cloud with certain database mapping/ logic.

Question:

Can I've a unique id (line 122424-3213-23423423) into my MS Word Document (database id) when it's downloaded from the Web Application?

Why I need it (unique id)?

I'll use this id when the document is being updated from the MS Word to map/ update the correct document.

Any help is highly appreciated on this.

Comment: It's not clear what you have in mind, here? At what point should the ID be written to the document? Is your question where to store it? What technology would be doing the updating (how would it be accessing the document)?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you would like to add some meta data to your Word documents.

You could use [CustomDocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.documentbase.customdocumentproperties?view=vsto-2017).

Generally, its a Dictionary (key/value) that is stored in the document and it's accessible via Word interop.

Lets say that your property name is "`DatabaseId`".

Get the properties collection:

```
var props = (Office.DocumentProperties)app.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties
```

So, use this code to **set** the value:

```
props.Add("DatabaseId", false, Microsoft.Office.Core
            .MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, "122424-3213-23423423");
```

**Get** value:

```
props["DatabaseId"].Value
```

Comment: Sure, please look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

**Server Side Code (.NET Core)**
When any MS Office Document is being downloaded from the Web Application, I'm writing the corresponding Database ID into the document's meta tag. This ID is helpful for me in my VSTO Add-In to update the existing document.

Refer [this to create SetCustomProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-set-a-custom-property-in-a-word-processing-document)

```
public async Task SetCustomTag(string documentPath)
    {
         OpenXmlUtils.SetCustomProperty(documentPath, "CUSTOM-ID", "111-222-23333", OpenXmlUtils.PropertyTypes.Text);
    }
```

**VSTO Add-In**

```
public static string GetCustomMetaTagId(Document document)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties prps = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)document.CustomDocumentProperties;

        string customId = "";

        try
        {
            customId  = prps != null && prps["CUSTOM-ID"] != null ? prps["CUSTOM-ID"].Value : "";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        return customId  ;
    }
```